# Why should I use the Assert class methods?

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing

I find the `Assert` class methods rather confusing than helpful. I find it especially annoying that Microsoft's MSTest methods expect (or require?) me to write comparisons backwards, i. e. the constant/expected value first and the variable/actual value second. This is contradictory to natural language and hence to many programming guidelines for general comparisons in code.

So instead of this:

```
Assert.AreEqual(5, value, "Value is not correct.");
```

What's wrong with this, more normally looking test instruction:

```
if (value != 5) Assert.Fail("Value is not correct.");
```

This is what all the code looks like. It's what every programmer's eye is trained to see and understand really quickly. And the other assertion methods can be written in regular code just as easily.

With C# 6's `using static` you could even leave away the `Assert.` part.

I couldn't find any reasoning about this on the web and with the Assert class documentation.

Comment: Do you know [fluent assertions](http://www.fluentassertions.com/)?

Comment: Just switch to NUnit, XUnit or any other unit testing framework; personally i find the MSTest syntax just fine, takes the first 10 tests to get used to and then all sweet.

Comment: @RenéVogt Didn't know that and I see no point in discarding language features with custom methods. Less readable to me, and redundant things to learn.

Comment: @zaitsman Just checked but NUnit (is it still current?) and xUnit are backwards, too.

Comment: @ygoe i'm not sure what you checked...https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/Assertions `Assert.That(value, Is.EqualTo(42));` -> how is that backwards?

Comment: @zaitsman I just looked at the `Assert.AreEqual`-style methods. I know nothing about what other syntaxes these libs support. That fluent thing tends to be very chatty and more complicated to type. I could use a simple `if` as well, it's no less readable (if you know code).

Comment: @ygoe mate if you want to do something nobody can stop you. Is it best practice? no. Is it going to raise questions when you share the project with anyone else? yes. Should you do it? up to you.

Answer (score 7):

In `Assert.AreEqual(5, value, "Value is not correct.");` the message you receive will contain something like

> Expected 5, got 3 instead

In `if (value != 5) Assert.Fail("Value is not correct.");` the message will be

> Value is not correct.

Witch is much less informative as you don't have the value caused the assertion failure.

Answer (score 0):

MSTest uses the very common AAA pattern (arrange-act-assert). Your second instruction will be less readable for every other programmer, experienced with unit testing. Also you need to provide an additional information in second case, you need to extend your message and specify the expected and actual values manually, which requires more coding and can be avoided in the first case.